# Поиск слова в файле (без вспомогательных коллекций)

Tags: java, файлы, потоки-данных

Господа, добрый день.  Прошу помощи.

Нужно написать код, который поможет установить факт наличия слова в файле (т.е. результат тупо true/false). К примеру — у меня есть файл .txt, и мне нужно определить, есть ли в нём слово (например "stackoverflow")?

Но! В массив записывать нельзя. Задача в том, что нужно установить факт наличия слова в процессе чтения файла. Подскажите куда копать?

P.S. 1000 извинений господа, я неправильно объявил ограничения: мне разрешено использовать массив — нельзя коллекции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Java 8**

```
public boolean fileContainsWord(String fileName, String word) throws IOException {
    return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName))).contains(word);
}
```

Без использования contains:

```
public boolean fileContainsWord(String fileName, String word) throws IOException {

    return Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
            .map(line -> line.split(" *"))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .distinct()
            .anyMatch(w -> w.equals(word));
}
```

Comment: Плохое решение, если файл очень большой то все это упадет на OOM

Comment: Откровенно говоря я даже не знаю какое это решение. Выглядит великолепно, но я ещё не проходил Arrays, map и не могу понять что тут происходит. Мне бы подсказать как это можно реализовать на уровне совсем новичка.

Answer (score 0):

Моя вина - забыл уточнить. Мне запрещено использовать методы contains(…) и
indexOf(…). Я полагаю от меня требуют реализацию поиска с помощью либо Scanner, либо что то из Readera(a)

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось так:

```
boolean isContains = Files
            .lines(Paths.get("file.txt"))
            .anyMatch(e->e.contains("word"));
```

Не понимаю как можно не используя `contains` определить содержание. Можно написать вместо этого свой аналог, но суть такая же.

Comment: Наверное хотят проверить умение на посимвольное чтение файла (буферизированное или нет) и последовательное сравнение.

Comment: @Morewind или реализацию какого нибудь известного алгоритмы поиска.

Comment: Вот это скорее всего. Выручайте - покажите хоть в какую сторону копать, а дальше я по учебникам.

Comment: @Дмитрий https://github.com/izebit/Library/tree/master/src/main/java/ru/izebit/algorithms/string